# How to terminate the source observable from Observer's onNext method

Tags: rx-java

I wonder what is the best way to terminate the source observable from Observer's onNext method.

For example, I want that a button event emits only once when the validation would be OK. However, when the validation would be failed, a button event can emit again.

What I can think of is below.

```
Observable....
    .subscribe(new Subscriber(){
        public void onNext(T t){
            // do something and terminate the Observable
            // only when the validate method return true
            if (validate(t)){
                 doSomething(t);
                 unsubscribe();
            }
         }
         ...
     });
```

However, if I need an onCompleted event, it doesn't work.
Moreover, I'm not sure about calling `onCompleted()` from Observer's `onNext()`

Also, I think that to bring the validation into Observable would be not a good idea since Observer must have the responsibility of validation.
Moreover, in the case of "Hot" Observable, the validation might be different from each Observer if the observable has some observers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an operator like `takeUntil` or `takeWhile` for these kinds of cases:

```
Observable....
    .takeUntil(t -> validate(t))
    .subscribe(t -> doSomething(t));
```

**Hint in general:** read the [API documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html). Most of the answers are already available there. Also in some situations it helps when you draw a marble diagram yourself and then compare it to the drawings on the referred page. Finally, you can have [a more interactive experience](http://rxmarbles.com/) for certain operators.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I knew the operator but I couldn't get this idea. Since the observable's source were one object, I forced myself to use one observable to handle different validation of each observer. However, in this case, I can create some observables. The most difficult part of using Rx might be to think flexibly, I think. Again, thank you very much!!